# Saving a form with the switch button in Laravel 8.x and adding it to the enum table

Tags: php, laravel, enums, switch-statement, crud

My problem is that when adding data, the value goes "on" and it gives an error in recording to the database section. If it is "off", it does not record.

My migration table as below and table name ise cities

```
 $table->bigIncrements('id');
 $table->string('title');
 $table->enum('status', ['active', 'passive'])->default('active');
```

HTML classic form is below

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <span class="switch">
    <label>
      <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Please City Name"/>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('Required') }}</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <span class="switch">
    <label>
      <input name="status" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('Is it active?') }}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CityController is below I used helper and request.

```
public function store(CityStoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $data = $this->helper->clean($request);

        $hotels = $this->service->store($data);

        return back()->with(['status' => __('Ok! Recorded.')]);
    }
```

CityStoreRequest code is below. When I select required here, if I make the button passive, the record is not added and add the required fields.

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

CityService

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Repositories\CityRepository;

class CityService
{
    /**
     * @var CityRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * Service constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->repository = new CityRepository();
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index(array $data)
    {
        return $this->repository->index($data);
    }

    /**
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function show(int $id)
    {
        return $this->repository->show($id);
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(array $data)
    {
        return $this->repository->store($data);
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $data
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(array $data, int $id)
    {
        return $this->repository->update($data, $id);
    }

    /**
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function destroy(int $id)
    {
        return $this->repository->destroy($id);
    }
}
```

Repository as below

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\City;

class CityRepository
{
    /**
     * @var City
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $perPage = 25;

    /**
     * Repository constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->city = new City();
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index(array $data)
    {
        return $this->city->filter($data)->paginate($this->perPage);
    }

    /**
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function show(int $id)
    {
        return $this->city->findOrFail($id);
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(array $data)
    {
        return $this->city->create($data);
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $data
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(array $data, int $id)
    {
        $hotel = $this->city->findOrFail($id);

        $hotel->fill($data);

        $hotel->save();

        return $hotel;
    }

    /**
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function destroy(int $id)
    {
        $hotel = $this->city->findOrFail($id);

        $hotel->delete();

        return $hotel;
    }
}
```

In your opinion, where I need to check the data coming from the form and take the necessary actions.

Comment: Where is your city model. Make sure status is in the `$fillable`

Comment: @MuaRachmann yes sure there are $fillable

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to use `boolean` field instead of `enum`.

But if you want to use enum (maybe for any further statuses), use the simple way:

1. Add attribute `value` to checkbox. `<input ... value="active" />`
2. Validate incoming `status`.
3. Just save it like other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You would check (`validate`) input from your form in your validation. For you this is in your `CityStoreRequest` on the `rules()` function:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'status' => ['required', in:active,passive],
    ];
}
```

This uses the [`in`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in) validation rule of Laravel to determine if the value for the input is included in the given comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

'title' => 'required',
'status' => 'required', "in:active,passive",

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).